# Finding map from Klein bottle to $RP^2$ that induces an epimorphism of fundamental groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to find a map from the Klein bottle to $RP^2$ that induces an epimorphism of fundamental groups. Since the fundamental group of $RP^2$ is $Z_2$, intuitively it feels like a good start would be to look for any non-trivial map from $K$ to $RP^2$, but frankly even that is difficult for me. After reading quite a bit about the Klein bottle i still have problems even visualizing it, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should contract a loop $\gamma$ with $[\gamma] = 1$ in $\pi_1(K)$, and this should gives you $\Bbb RP^2$. It's true because $K$ is the blow-up of $\Bbb RP^2$ but there should be an elementary argument.

Comment: Please write your questions so that they are understandable even in the absence of their title.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sure, edited already. Is there a practical reason for this?

Comment: When you edit a question, there is no need to add "EDITED" or anything similar. Just edit them so that the end result is a correct text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N.H.'s answer is excellent. Here is an alternative way to visualise the map from the Klein bottle to the real projective plane suggested by N.H:

[image]

To go from the Klein bottle (left -hand picture) to the real projective plane (right-hand picture), I'm quotienting out the circle marked with the double-headed arrow.

To make contact with N.H.'s explanation: If you take a small open strip around the circle with the double headed arrow, you have a Mobius band. After quotienting out the circle, the Mobius band becomes a small open disk covering the black blob on left and right of the diagram of the real projective plane.

Since you say that it's hard to visualise these spaces, I should probably also explain how to make sense of these pictures.

- The Klein bottle: Start with a square. If you glue the two vertical sides (marked with the double-headed arrows), you get cylinder. If you then glue the two horizontal sides (marked with the single-headed arrows) in the obvious way, you get a torus. To get a Klein bottle instead of a torus, you need to do the gluing in such a way that these horizontal sides come together with "opposite orientation relative to each other" - hence why the single-headed arrows point in opposite directions in my picture of the Klein bottle.
- The real projective plane is the space of all rays through the origin in 3-dimensional space. This is the same as the sphere with opposite points identified. (Imagine a unit sphere sitting in $\mathbb R^3$, and identify each ray with the two points where it intersects the unit sphere...) This in turn is the same as the northern hemisphere, with antipodal points identified on the equator. And this is what I have drawn.

Comment: +1, I think with the argument with the diagram identification is better for explaining why the total space was homeomorphic to the Klein bottle.

Comment: @N.H. I really like your idea though! I never knew that the Klein bottle is a (real) blowup of $\mathbb {RP}^2$!

Comment: Thanks ! In fact real points of Hirzebruch surfaces $\Sigma_n$ form a torus if $n$ is even and a Klein bottle if $n$ is odd as it is a circle bundle over the circle with $n$ twists. This observation leads to interesting stuff with real algebraic curves so I wanted to use the "algebraic-geometry" solution :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "quotienting out the circle marked with the double-headed arrow"? I know that a horizontal line on the diagram on the left is a circle since we glue the vertical lines with double headed arrows, but i'm not sure what exactly are you quotienting out here.

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes Sure. If $X$ is a topological space and $Y \subset X$ is a subspace, then one can define the quotient space $X / Y$, and one has a natural projection map $p : X \to X / Y$. For us, $X$ is the Klein bottle, $Y$ is the circle marked with the double arrow, $X / Y$ is the real projective plane, and the map from $X$ to $X / Y$ that induces the epimorphism of fundamental groups is the projection map $p : X \to X / Y$.

Comment: @KennyWong Sorry i should have clarified. I know what quotienting is, i just meant to ask what circle are we talking about. As far as i understand the diagram the double headed arrow does not mark a circle, but a sort of line alongside the klein bottle, am i wrong here?

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes The double headed arrow **does** mark a circle! When you glue the single-headed edges, the top-left vertex gets identified with the bottom-right vertex, and the top-right vertex gets identified with the bottom-left vertex. When you glue the double-headed edges, the top-left vertex gets identified with the top-right vertex, and the bottom-left vertex gets identified with the bottom-right vertex. So **all four vertices are the same point**.

Comment: @KennyWong Oh my bad, the double headed arrow's endpoints are identified in the diagram so of course it is as you say. I think I get it all now, thanks for the patience, you really helped me understand all 3 answers (and why they are referring to the same thing in fact, as far as i get it).

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes The single-arrow-circle and the double-arrow-circle are precisely the two generators of the fundamental group of the Mobius band!

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes Let me also explain how to intuitively see what the fundamental group of the Mobius band is, by staring at the picture. Call the single-arrow-circle $a$ and call the double-arrow-circle $b$. These are all non-trivial cycles. Except...

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes Except that $ba = a^{-1} b$. For example, $ba$ can be visualised as bottom-left to top-left to top-right. Whereas $a^{-1} b$ can be visualised as bottom-left to bottom-right to top-right. The two paths can be continuously deformed from one to the other across the interior of the square. Hence the fundamental group of the Klein bottle is $\langle a, b : ba = a^{-1} b \rangle$. There is even a rigorous proof that perfectly captures this intuition - it uses the van Kampen theorem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64309/discussion-between-themountainthatcodes-and-kenny-wong).

Comment: **Note:** "fundamental group of Mobius band" should have read "fundamental group of Klein bottle"

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following transformation : take a small disk in $RP^2$, remove it and glue a Moebius band $M$. You get a space $Y$, I claim it is homeomorphic to the Klein bottle.

If $E \subset M$ generates $\pi_1(M)$ (it is the straight line in the picture), you have a projection $M \to D$, sending the boundary of $M$ to the boundary of $D$, which send the complement of $M \ E$ to $D \backslash 0$ with $p(E) = 0$.

[image]

You can extends such projection to $K \to RP^2$ and this gives the morphism you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two connected manifolds of dimension $n \geq 2$.

There is a map $\varphi : X\# Y \to X$ given by mapping $Y$ to a disc $D$. By the Seifert van Kampen theorem, $\pi_1(X\# Y) \cong \pi_1(X^{\circ})*_{\pi_1(S^{n-1})}\pi_1(Y^{\circ})$ where $X^{\circ}$ denotes $X$ with an embedded open disc removed; likewise for $Y^{\circ}$. The map $\varphi$ induces a map

$$\varphi_* : \pi_1(X^{\circ})*_{\pi_1(S^{n-1})}\pi_1(Y^{\circ}) \to \pi_1(X^{\circ})*_{\pi_1(S^{n-1})}\pi_1(D) \cong \pi_1(X)$$

which is the identity on the subgroup $\pi_1(X^{\circ})$ and necessarily trivial on $\pi_1(Y^{\circ})$ (because $\pi_1(D)$ is trivial). In particular, $\varphi_*$ is an epimorphism.

As $K = \mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2$, we obtain a map $\varphi : K \to \mathbb{RP}^2$ inducing an epimorphism $\varphi_* : \pi_1(K) \to \pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2)$.

Comment: To clarify, by $RP^2 \# RP^2$ you mean the space obtained by removing a small disk from each $RP^2$ and gluing them along the boundaries of the removed disks (not entirely familiar with the notation)? If so, is there an easy argument or a link to a source for $K = RP^2 \# RP^2$?

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes Look at the pictures. $\mathbb{RP}^2$ with a disk removed is a Mobius band. (This is clearest if you remove a disk around the fat blob - just be careful because in the picture, this disk will be split between the left- and right-hand sides). As for the Klein bottle - if you cut the diagram of the Klein bottle in half, using a vertical cut down the middle, then the two halves will both be Mobius bands. If I'm not mistaken, the map that Michael is suggesting is the same as the one that N.H. is suggesting.

Comment: @KennyWong By fat blob you're refering to the antipodal points you marked on your drawing?

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes Yes.

Comment: @KennyWong Ok i see what you mean now.